Let $g : X \to Z$ and $h : Z \to Y$ be smooth maps. Show that $\deg(h \circ g) = 0$.
This question is from an old old publicly available qualifying exam that I’m using to learn this field (Stanford geometry and topology). I used Hatcher's book for reference. All work is my own.


Suppose $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are closed oriented manifolds such that
$$
\dim(X) = \dim(Y) > \dim(Z).
$$
Let $g : X \to Z$ and $h : Z \to Y$ be smooth maps. Show that $\deg(h \circ g) = 0$.

Answer: From Hatcher, we know that the degree of a non-surjective map is zero. A map between a lower-dimensional manifold to a higher-dimensional manifold cannot be surjective. Thus $h$ has a degree of zero, as will any precomposition of $h$.

This answer seemed too straightforward to me, so is there something I am missing? Did I not understand properly what Hatcher was saying about degrees?


A map between a lower-dimensional manifold to a higher-dimensional manifold cannot be surjective.

This is (surprisingly) not true, the problem being things like space-filling curves. But you can argue that such a map is necessarily homotopy equivalent to a non-surjective one, and I believe such an argument is somewhere in Hatcher.

I'm very rusty on my algebraic topology, and was never so great at it in the first place, but is it not possible to reason directly via the definition of degree? The degree is just the integer $n$ such that the induced map on top homology is multiplication by $n$, right? But if the map $X \to Y$ factors through $Z$, then the map on homology also factors, and if $m = dim(X)$, then $H_{m}(Z)$ should be zero, since $m > dim(Z)$...

(Also, the point about space-filling curves is a good one, but the maps in the question are assumed to be smooth. Is there an example of a surjective map from a lower-dim manifold to a higher-dim one which is also smooth? This is definitely outside my wheelhouse, but my instinct was that this can't be true by Sard's theorem.)

@AlexWertheim oh, excellent catch. I don't believe there can be a smooth surjective map from an $m$-manifold to an $n$-manifold for $n > m$, and I think your proof by Sard's theorem is right. (Everything in the image is an irregular value so the image has measure 0). Your degree argument is also correct.
